# Apache Virtual Host Aliasing

Tags: apache, alias

I'm trying to setup some aliasing on the site I am working on. At the moment this is a front-end only specific build that I have setup on my local host. My problem arises from the need to deep link to specific sections of the page. As the user scrolls down the page the URL gets updated via JavaScript.

For example when I load the page my URL is: *local-www.blahblah.com/en-US/home.html*

As I scroll down the page and certain elements come into view the URL gets changed. For example it could become...

*local-www.blahblah.com/en-US/category/title-1/*

*local-www.blahblah.com/en-US/category/title-2/*

What I need to be able to do is to go to that new URL, either via a refresh or direct input and have that bring up the *home.html* file while keeping the URL intact.

For example: I type in *local-www.blahblah.com/en-US/category/title/* and it loads the *home.html* as that URL.

I thought I could simply do this with an Alias with a wildcard in my virtual host config but that's not working for me.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:82>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/blahblah.com/deploy"
    ServerName local-www.blahblah.com
    Alias /en-US/* /en-US/home.html
</VirtualHost>
```

My Apache knowledge is beginner level so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use mod_rewrite, first off all, you need to enable modrewrite . If you use debian/ubuntu, you need to create a symlink in the directory /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

```
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load .
```

And you add this configuration in your VirtualHost

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/en-US/?(.*)$ /en-US/home.html [L]
```

The first line enable the module
I use a regex to restrict the rewrite rule :

> ^/en-US =  URL must start with /en-US
>  /? = the / is
>   optional 
>  (.*)$ = any character , I use () to grouping content so
>   it give you the option to reuse it with the variable $1

here an example to use the variable :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/en-US/?(.*)$ /en-US/home.php?Var=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Perfect! This seems to do just what I need. Man I was way off with my assumption about Alias. Haha. Back to the front-end for me! Thanks again.